# ASP C# Bootstrap - Abrir modal da MasterPage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-3, webforms, modal

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver sites com o ASPX C#, usando o Bootstrap.
Antes, quero dizer que já pesquisei de tudo e não encontrei uma solução pro problema que estou encontrando, então, por favor, se alguém puder me ajudar.

Na minha MasterPage, tenho no `<header>` a declaração da ativação do modal, conforme segue:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Estilo de Personalização da Página...                       -->
<link href="/Content/PersonalStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModalDanger() {
        $('#ModalDanger').modal('show');
    }

    function closeModalDanger() {
        $('#ModalDanger').modal('hide');
    }
</script>
```

Depois no `<body>` da MasterPage, após definir o menu, vem o código abaixo:

```
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="FormBody" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalDanger" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalDanger" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" runat="server">
            <div class="modal-content" runat="server">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: red; color: whitesmoke;" runat="server">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4>Atenção!!!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" runat="server" style="margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 20px;">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDanger1" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDanger2" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDanger3" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" runat="server" style="background-color: red;">
                    <%--<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnDangerClose" runat="server" type="button" >Fechar</button>--%>
                    <asp:Button runat="server" class="btn btn-default" ID="btnDangerCloseAsp" Text="Fechar" OnClick="btnDangerCloseAsp_OnClick" UseSubmitBehavior="false" data-dismiss="modal" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Acima do `<header>`, coloquei um input oculto, se necessário, para guardar o link de direcionamento da página.

```
    <div>
        <input id="LinkAcess" value="" type="hidden" runat="server" />
    </div>
```

No final da MasterPage, declaro a jQuery e depois o Bootstrap conforme segue:

```
    </footer>
    <!-- Footer -->
</form>

<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

No Code Behind, declarei o método para ativar o Modal quando necessário:

```
public void MessageDanger(string sTextLine01, string sTextLine02, string sTextLine03, string sLink = "")
        {
            lblDanger1.Text = sTextLine01;
            lblDanger2.Text = sTextLine02;
            lblDanger3.Text = sTextLine03;

            RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "MensagemDeAtencao", "$(function() { openModalDanger(); });", true);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLink))
            {
                LinkAcess.Value = sLink;
            }
        }
```

Como visto, este método recebe os textos a serem apresentados no Modal e se, e somente se, "sLink" for atribuído, atribui ao input oculto.

Ainda no Code Behind, declarei o método:

```
    protected void btnDangerCloseAsp_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(LinkAcess.Value))
        {
            var sLinkAcess = LinkAcess.Value;
            LinkAcess.Value = "";
            Server.Transfer(sLinkAcess, true);
        }
    }
```

Atribuindo o link a uma variável e limpando o input; com isto, ao clicar no fechar, se for o caso, redireciona para a página indicada.

Na página filha, a exemplo, quando o acesso não é válido, chamo o método:

```
    private void AcessoInvalido()
    {
        ((PublicMasterPage)Master).MessageDanger("Por favor, verifique seu e-mail e tente novamente!",
                         "Informações necessárias não encontradas.",
                         "Você será redirecinado a Página Inicial!",
                         "/Default.aspx");
    }
```

Situação atual, da página filha, consigo acessar "MessageDanger", que recebe os parâmetros e atribui tudo como esperado, sem erros, passa pela linha do "RegisterClientScriptBlock" sem erro, mas não apresenta o modal, neste exemplo, abre a página "Default.apsx".

A coisa é que não abre o modal, já tentei chamar o script usando "RegisterStartupScript" e "RegisterClientScriptBlock", mas não deu certo.

Tentei outra dica que encontrei usando o "UpdatePanel" e não deu certo também.

Estou trabalhando com MVC e WebForms e sempre que eu precisar colocar uma mensagem na tela, quero usar o modal, por isto a atribuição do Text dos Labels. Quando em uma validação no Banco de Dados, a exemplo, e-mail já cadastrado, CPF já cadastrado, Código inexistente, am fim, qualquer evento que eu necessite informar o operador ou usuário, estarei utilizando os modais (Danger, Alert e Info), além de outros 2 para apresentação de textos explicativos conforme necessário, e isto, creio que somente pelo Code Behinde, pois pelo APSx eu utilizaria os Validators, eu acho!

Como coloquei, estou aprendendo, se tem forma melhor, estou aberto!

Alguém sabe me orientar qual o caminho certo a seguir?

Comment: Só uma correção:

Comment: Só uma correção:

public void MessageDanger(string sTextLine01, string sTextLine02, string sTextLine03, string sLink = "")
        {
            lblDanger1.Text = sTextLine01;
            lblDanger2.Text = sTextLine02;
            lblDanger3.Text = sTextLine03;

            RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "MensagemDeAtencao", "$(function() { openModalDanger(); });", true);

            if (**! string.IsNullOrEmpty(sLink))       <=====[**
            {
                Server.Transfer(sLink);
            }
        }

Comment: E tu precisa abrir o modal do code behind mesmo? Em qual situação tu precisa abrir o modal?

Comment: Sempre que eu precisar colocar uma mensagem na tela, quero usar o modal, por isto a atribuição do Text dos Labels. Quando em uma validação no Banco de Dados, a exemplo, e-mail já cadastrado, CPF já cadastrado, Código inexistente, am fim, qualquer evento que eu necessite informar o operador ou usuário, estarei utilizando os modais (Danger, Alert e Info), além de outros 2 para apresentação de textos explicativos!
E isto, creio que somente pelo Code Behinde, pois pelo APSx eu utilizaria os Validators, eu acho!

Como coloquei, estou aprendendo, se tem forma melhor, estou aberto!

Comment: Tu tá usando webapi? ou webforms?

Comment: WebForms!......

Comment: Tu pode editar o post e adicionar a info que colocou no comentário e trocar a tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei o código do jeito que tu postou:

código de abertura/fechamento da modal na masterPage e no codebehind do webform fiz a chamada:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "openModalDanger();", true);
```

Acontece que, se eu deixar o script:

```
function openModalDanger() {
    $('#ModalDanger').modal();
}
```

Não abre a modal. 
Mas então alterei para:

```
function openModalDanger() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#ModalDanger').modal();
    }, 500);
}
```

E a modal abriu.

Acontece que a chamada do webform acontecia antes da renderização do HTML da modal, que estava como último conteúdo do body. Então, basta você levar todo o HTML da modal como primeiro bloco de código do body na masterPage. Mantenha seu script no header e vai funcionar.

Lembrando que, quando for adicionar esse script ao head, será necessário ter carregado antes dele, o jquery e bootstrap, nessa ordem, ok?

Fica minha opinião de que não acho bacana o servidor ficar chamando client. Parece que as coisas fica minvertidas, não? Pense em utilizar variaveis de retorno, de repente, e tratar da verificação e chamada do js no js.

segue a sequência dos testes:

MasterPage

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<html lang="pt">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> - Meu aplicativo ASP.NET</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function openModalDanger() {
            $('#ModalDanger').modal();
        }

        function closeModalDanger() {
            $('#ModalDanger').modal('hide');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="ModalDanger" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalDanger" runat="server">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" runat="server">
            <div class="modal-content" runat="server">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: red; color: whitesmoke;" runat="server">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4>Atenção!!!</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" runat="server" style="margin-top: 25px; padding-top: 20px;">
                    <br />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDanger1" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDanger2" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True" />
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDanger3" runat="server" Text="" Visible="True" />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" runat="server" style="background-color: red;">
                    <%--<button class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" id="btnDangerClose" runat="server" type="button" >Fechar</button>--%>
                    <input type="button" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form runat="server">
        ...
    </form>
</body>
```

E a chamada testei direto no pageLoad da default.aspx, o primeiro bloco de código do post:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "script", "openModalDanger();", true);
```

Comment: O primeiro eu testei e não deu certo
No mais, declarei os scipts no final, pois lí em muitos que seria melhor no final, como estou aprendendo a programação Web, decidi seguir, mas tua colocação é forte.
No caso de retorno, nas três modais que listei (Danger, Alert e Info), não há necessidade, pois são somente informações apresentadas, já na ModalYesNo, eu faço a validação pra saber qual botão recebeu o clique.
Vou subir as Divs e o Script como aconselhou e ver!

Comment: Está correto sobre os scripts no final. Porque entendemos que, todo o html e os estilos foram carregados a página estaria qse pronta, então é hora dos tratamentos, atribuições de eventos e etc. Mas nesse seu caso, se tu chamar o script, supomos, no pageLoad dum webform, e adicionar o script só no final da master, vai ter uma mensagem de: a função: abc() é indefinida/não encontrada. Vai precisar ter o script adicionado antes e o html da modal renderizado antes.

Comment: Ah, e lembrando que, quando tu levar o script pro header, executando isso, será necessário ter carregado o jquery e bootstrap antes disso, ok?

Comment: Aline, segui tuas indicações, subi os scripts, os modais, mantendo-os dentro do `<body><form>` , alterei o script "openModalDanger", testei algumas vezes, alterando e tudo mais, mas não funcionou!
Se houvesse como, te mandaria todo o projeto, pois creio que com tua expertise, facilmente diria onde está o erro! Mas agradeço, descobrindo algo, por favor, me ajude!

Comment: Bem, @ArnaldoOliveira, coloquei todo o código ali. Testei e está funcionando... Tu tá vendo algum erro no console ou coisa assim qndo chama o script?

Comment: Não dá erro algum, passa normal quando debugo..  :-( .

Comment: Tá. Ultimo teste que consigo pensar: function openModalDanger() { console.log("elementos: " + $('#ModalDanger').length); 
            $('#ModalDanger').modal();
        } o que é impresso aí?

Comment: Ok! Comentei o método e colei o que você postou, também comentei o direcionamento para a página default, a ModalDanger apareceu.

Declarei no Code Behinde da MasterPage "protected string LinkAcess { get; set; }"; antes de chamar a Modal, atribuí o valor de "sLink" a "LinkAcess" e no "OnClick" do botão Fechar da Modal, iria para a página deseja, mas "LinkAcess" está nula, o valor atribuido não ficou. Agora o erro é outro e tenho que ver porque não está vindo o valor atribuído.

A Modal está aparecendo agora!!! Valeu e muito!!!!

Comment: Aline, grato pela atenção e por compartilhar tua expertise! Este assunto está encerrado!!! Eu acho! Objetivo alcançado!!!

Comment: Ótimo, @ArnaldoOliveira. Se a resposta te ajudou, tu pode marcar como certa pra que possa ajudar outras pessoas também. (=

Comment: Perdoe minha ignorância, mas como faze-lo?

Comment: Tem um certinho abaixo do número ao lado esquerdo da resposta. =)